# Complex sql select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't figure out how to make this sql select statement...Here are my tables :

[image]

I opened the tables concerned by the request

So basically `I want to select the number of albums for each interpret.` 
I just can't figure it out... I am currently thinking that I need to do my first select on album like :

```
select interpret.no_interpret, count(*)
from album
.
.
.
group by interpret.no_interpret;
```

and there work from this but I don't know where to go next.

Comment: select interpret.no_interpret, count(*)
from album group by interpret.no_interpret;

Comment: How are `album` and `interpret` tables **related**? Can you please identify `Primary` and `Foreign` keys?

Comment: it appears interpret relates to link_InterpretSong through NO_Interpret, Song to LInk_Interpret_song though No_Song; but I don't see how No_Album relates to song or interpret.  Without this knowledge I don't think anyone could help

Comment: the song contains the no_album as a foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but I'm not seeing the direct relation from your song table to the album...

I would first start by getting the link_interpret_song table joined to the song table and get count of distinct albums.  However, I didn't see what appears to be a "No_Album" column in the field list of the song table.  I can only guess it IS in there associated to the particular album.  I did see media, but to me, that would be like a TYPE of media (digital, download, vinyl, CD) vs the actual ID Key apparent to the album table.

That said, I am thinking there IS such a "No_Album" column in the SONG table.

```
select
      LIS.No_Interpret,
      COUNT( DISTINCT S.No_Album )
   from
      Link_Interpret_Song LIS
         JOIN Song S
            on LIS.No_Song = S.No_Song
   group by
      LIS.No_Interpret;
```

Now, that said, if you want the interpret details, take the above results and join that to the interpret table.  I've done both distinct album count and total # of songs just as an example of count() vs count(distinct) context... such as

```
select
      PreCounts.No_Interpret,
      PreCounts.DistinctAlbums,
      PreCounts.ActualSongs,
      I.Name_Interpret,
      I.First_Name,
      I.Stage_Name
   from
      ( select
              LIS.No_Interpret,
              COUNT( DISTINCT S.No_Album ) as DistinctAlbums,
              COUNT(*) as ActualSongs
           from
              Link_Interpret_Song LIS
                 JOIN Song S
                    on LIS.No_Song = S.No_Song
           group by
              LIS.No_Interpret ) as PreCounts
      JOIN Interpret I
         ON PreCounts.No_Interpret = I.No_Interpret
```

Comment: yes I never realized that I didn't linked the song to the album but I always took for granted that I had a foreing key of the album in the song. I going to fix this and try your solution. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous since there isn't a clear indication of how the tables are related.  Given assumptions about these relations, your query will likely take on something similar to the following form:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.no_album) from album a, interpret i, song s 
where i.no_song=s.no_song 
and a.no_album=s.no_album GROUP BY i.no_interpret
```